# Angular directive input decimal 2 digit

Tags: angular, input, decimal, directive

I have implemented the following directive on an input field to allow the user to enter a decimal number with 2 digits

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDigitDecimaNumber]'
})
export class DigitDecimaNumberDirective {
  @Input() numberDecimal = 2;

  // Allow decimal numbers

  // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
  // Backspace, tab, end, home
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent): any{
    let after = {re : ``}
    if(this.numberDecimal == 0 ){
     after.re =  `^[0-9]*$`;
    }else{
      after.re = `^[0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]{0,${this.numberDecimal}}?$`;
    }

    const regex: RegExp = new RegExp(after.re);
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;

    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key === 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');

    if (!this.omit_number(event)){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (next && !String(next).match(regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  omit_number(event: any): any {
    let key;
    key = event.charCode;
    return ((key > 47 && key < 58) || key === 46 || key === 44);
  }
}
```

The problem is that this directive only works on an Android mobile. It still allows letters when I want the letters to be blocked. When debugging with an android, I noticed that charCode is still at 0 and that event.ket is still undefined.

How to have a directive that works on both PC and android